# Difference between (function($) {})(jQuery) and jQuery(function() {});

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, syntax

I have a jQuery plugin minified and located at the very bottom of a script, and one of the functions is called somewhere in the middle of the script **on page load**.

Now method 1 generates an error, please see the following simplified code

```js
//method 1: red is not a function!
/*
(function($) {
    $("#foo").red();
})(jQuery);
*/

// method 2: this works
jQuery(function() {
    $("#foo").red();
});

// plugin
(function($) {
    $.fn.red = function() {
        return $(this).css("color", "red");
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Can someone explain the difference between these 2 methods? What causes the error in method 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between the two is the second one waits for the DOM to be ready with wrapping the code with:

```
$(function(){
    // code in here will be executed once the DOM is ready
});
```

and thus the plugin has time to "register itself" so you don't get the error saying `red` is not a function.

If you want the first version to wait for the DOM to be ready, use this:

```
(function($) { // $ is jQuery, prevents name collision with other frameworks
    $(function(){ // Register the code to fire after the DOM is ready
        $("#foo").red();
    });
})(jQuery); // Passes jQuery as a parameter so $ will be jQuery
```

As a side note, register all your plugins right after you load jQuery and all these problems will go away.